# How JBL app recognises the speaker name, colour etc, when connect via Bluetooth from my iPhone?

Tags: bluetooth

Few days back I bought Jbl Charge 3. When I connect the speaker with Jbl connect app on my iPhone I found it was giving some additional information apart from receiving audio file. It recognises that it's a jbl charge 3 and even knows that its is of red colour( I tried with black speaker it did same, recognise that it is black in colour). I am not from IT background. Can any one tell me how it works? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The JBL Charge 3 uses and transmits metadata from the speaker to your phone using different Bluetooth protocols listed below. HFP is the most likely of the candidates that transmit the information about your JBL Charge III. See below for more info.

1. A2DP V1.3 - Advanced Audio Distribution Profile. This is the Bluetooth Stereo profile which defines how high quality stereo audio can be streamed from one device to another over a Bluetooth connection.
2. AVRCP V1.5 - is typically used with A2DP devices for next/previous track selection and pause/play functions.
3. HFP V1.6 - is a hands-free protocol that transmits battery, allows phone calls to be passed through, and other functions of the phone that may be distracting.
4. HSP V1.2 - This is the most commonly used profile, providing support for the popular Bluetooth headsets to be used with mobile phones. It relies on SCO for audio encoded in 64 kbit/s CVSD or PCM and a subset of AT commands from GSM 07.07 for minimal controls including the ability to ring, answer a call, hang up and adjust the volume.

Source(s)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles

https://www.jbl.com/bluetooth-speakers/JBL+CHARGE+III.html